# Whats the right type of visa to deliver a training session in Schengen zone?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I've been invited to deliver a two-day technical training session in a German firm. It will be a paid training session.

I already have a long duration business visitor visa but since I will get paid for this session I don't think this is the appropriate visa.

Any thoughts on what may be the right visa type to apply for? i.e. This isn't really long term "employment" but on the other hand it is a remunerated activity.

PS. I found a lot of relevant details here now. In particular this bit is interesting but I cannot find more information on this:

> "In limited circumstances, foreign nationals may engage in specialized
>   professional and technical activities by obtaining an abbreviated work
>   permission under Paragraph 19 although certain strict preconditions
>   must be met. "

https://indien.ahk.de/fileadmin/AHK_Indien/user_upload/PDFS/News/Indo-German_Business_PDFs/Assignments_and_short_term_trips_of_Indian_employees_to_Germany.pdf

http://www.balglobal.com/bal-countries/germany-travel-and-visa-overview/

Comment: AFAIK the only appropriate visa for remunerated work is a residence and work permit.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks! But there seem to be a bunch of situations I can imagine where there's a few days of "work" but not really long term residence. e.g. technicians travelling to install or repair equipment, or a speaker called to speak at a conference that he gets paid for etc. I'm curious to see if there's another visa that covers these situations.

Comment: @Traveller many Schengen countries contemplate work authorization for short-term visitors on a C visa.  France is one of them.  I think Germany is, too, but I'm not certain.

Comment: In my experience, you don't need a work visa if you're going to the country for what we might call "non-productive" activities, such as meeting in person with co-workers, but you do need one if you'll be doing actual work (making sales calls, writing code, packing boxes, whatever).  In your case it sounds like productive work, so I suspect you'll need a work visa for it.  I think it would be hard to make a case for this being non-productive work if you're being specifically paid to do it.

Comment: @Kyralessa I agree.  That's why I am thinking my C class visa won't do but OTOH the long term residence permit etc. does not seem the right fit either. Basically this is very short duration productive work. e.g. Imagine a high profile speaker (not me) being called to deliver a motivational talk for which he gets speaking fees. What's the right visa type for that?

Comment: Who pays *you*, and which country are you from?

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks! The inviting company in Germany pays me. And I'm not a EU resident nor citizen.